# Can't add new 'object in array' using firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having problemas at understanding firestore.

I understand Collection as Array, and Document as value (object).

soy, I want to push a new object inside and array of array, so:

Collection 1, includes Collection A, B, C... etc.

I want to be able to push a new object, in Collection A, inside Collection 1. Is that possible?

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { addDoc, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from './firebase';

const useAppointmentDataBase = () => {
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

    const addNewAppointment = async (dateString, newAppointment) => {
        try {
            const appointmentCollectionRef = collection(
                db,
                'appointmentsDataBase',
                '1-2-3456'
            );

            await addDoc(appointmentCollectionRef, { test: 1, test: 2 });

            setSuccess(true);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error adding document: ', error);
        }
    };

    return { success, addNewAppointment };
};

export default useAppointmentDataBase;
```

And this is my firestore structure.

[image]

I tried to understand the documentation, but still being confused for me....

--- WHAT I WANT --- for Doug Stevenson, thanks!

I want to work a model of data in the next way (I'm also trying to explain correcly in english).

I want a main object (database), lets call it 1.

so 1 will have insede lo of arrays, lets call it A, B, C.

And thats arrays will have the objects I want.

Something like this.

```
1:{
A:[{},{},{}],
B:[{},{}]
}
```

The use for this is to save appointments by time, inside date.

For example, the date 1-1-1234 could have, 0, 1, or 5 appointments.

```
{hour:'9:30', customer:'Jhon'}
```

etc...

Comment: See [subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections). Collections can only be top-level or within a document.

Comment: I think your understanding of collections and documents in Firestore is not correct.  In your screenshot, the column on the left is a list of collections.  In the middle, a list of document IDs within the selected collection.  On the right, a list of fields and their values for the selected document.  Would you like to rephrase your question to use the terminology more correctly so it's easier to understand what you want?  It would be good if you can describe the final form of the document you want to create.  You can edit the question using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The data model of Firestore always alternates collections and documents.

- So at the root you have a list of top-level collections.
- Then in each collection you have a list of documents.
- Each of those documents can have field with values, *and*
- Under each of those documents, you can once have subcollections.

There is no way to directly nest collections under other collections.

As Doug commented, trying to compare this to arrays is not going to help you in the long run. Instead try to use the terminology as Firestore uses in its [introduction of the data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model).
If you're new to data modeling in Firestore, I also recommend watching the excellent [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) video series.